# We have a chat room: let's think of a clever name

Tags: discussion, chat

History has a SE chat room, something I only just realised. Most other chat rooms have a nickname. Can we think of something clever to call ours?

Some examples of other SE sites and their chat rooms:

- Stack Overflow = *The Heap*
- Linguistics = *lɪŋˈgwɪstɪks*
- Super User = *Root Access*
- Cooking = *The Frying Pan*
- Travel = *You Are Here*
- Writers = *The Overlook Hotel*
- Bicycles = *The Velodrome*

Comment: Could we have some examples of the other nicknames?

Comment: Oh just noticed Linguistics is in here! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion: The Time Machine

Comment: That's a good one.

Comment: there's not really a better one :)

Comment: In the end, I think this was the best suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Here are my suggestions:

"Here's What Happened"

"Something Happened"

"I Remember That"

I also like Steve's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This was really inspired by Steven Drennon's answer, but how about [The Wayback Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mister_Peabody)?

[image]

Hearkening back to one of my favorite cartoon bits as a kid. It was at least as accurate as The History Channel is today...

Comment: "Wayback machine" is already the name of the service offered by archive.org

Comment: @Lohoris - Yup. Its a favored name for things on the internet. I'll grant you that could be a big drawback.

Answer (score 0):

"Scripta manent"

"Hic sunt leones"